# check then update method in MyModel.m2m_field.through django

Tags: python, django

i want to update a field which have a M2M connection

for example :

```
class SelectMobile(models.Model):
    #others
    imei = models.ManyToManyField(Imei)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

and this is my Imei model

```
class Imei(models.Model):
   imei = models.CharField(max_length=15,verbose_name='IMEI',unique=True)
   mobile = models.ForeignKey(MobileModels,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

i need to update `active` in `Imei` only when an instance of `SelectMobile` been created and its `status` field equal to True i tried this

```
def update_imei_m2m(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    if instance.status == True: #this doesnt work , now it works on `Imei` instead of `SelectMobile`
        Imei.objects.filter(pk__in=kwargs.get('pk_set')).update(active=True)

m2m_changed.connect(update_imei_m2m,sender=SelectMobile.imei.through)
```

thanks for helping