# Using different fields in foreignkey django

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I have to use different fields as ForeignKey, not only `str` method field !?

I tried this but it seems that doesn't work and it only return `str` method fields data:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    invoice_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name

class ModelB(models.Model):
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(ModelA,to_field='invoice_id',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I need to show, in  `ModelB` invoice field, all `invoice_id`s, but it displays `product`s ? Thanks for helping

Comment: It does *not* save the `__str__` in the field. It saves a *reference* to the `ModelA` object (for example through the primary key, or through the `invoice_id`). But if you use `.invoice`, then it will *fetch* the corresponding `ModelA` object. If you want to access the `invoice_id` in `ModelB`, you can use `mymodelb.invoice_id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to use different fields for as ForeignKey not only str method field!?

A `ForeignKey` never uses the `str` method. It stores by default the primary key of the object it refers to. If you specify a [**`to_field=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field), then it will store *that* field.

However if you have a `ModelB` object `mymodelb`, and you access the `ForeignKey`, so `mymodelb.invoice`, it will lazily *fetch* the related object. It will thus in this case make a query that looks like `SELECT modela.* FROM modela WHERE invoice_id = …`.

If you wan the value that the `ForeignKey` stores, you can make use of `fieldname_id`, so in this case `.invoice_id`. This thus means that you can access the invoice id with:

```
mymodelb.invoice_id  # invoice_id of the referred ModelA object
```

If you want to show `invoice_id`s in a `Form`, you should override the [**`ModelChoiceField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield), then in the `ModelBForm` you can use this subclass:

```
from django import forms

class InvoiceChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return str(obj.invoice_id)

class ModelBForm(forms.ModelForm):
    invoice = InvoiceChoiceField(queryset=ModelA.objects.all())
```

But in that case, you do not need to specify a `to_field` at all in the `ForeignKey`.Models deal with how data is *stored*, not with how data is rendered.

Comment: thanks for replying , do you mean ModelA.invoice_id  inside ModelB ?it raise error (AttributeError: type object 'ModelA' has no attribute 'invoice_id')?

Comment: @art_cs: no, if you have a `ModelB` *object*, you can access `mymodelb.invoice_id` (so `mymodelb` is a `ModelB` object).

Comment: still confuse me , please can you write it inside the model class? i appreciate you

Comment: @art_cs: but the point is that you do not need to change anything to the model. You can simply, for a `ModelB` object, use `.invoice_id` to fetch the *target* field of the `invoice` foreignkey. So for a `ForeignKey` field `blabla`, it makes an extra field `blabla_id`.

Comment: i tried this in ModelB (invoice = models.ForeignKey(ModelA.invoice_id,on_delete=models.CASCADE) but it raised this error : (AssertionError: ForeignKey(<django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x000002113E6C9358>) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self')

Comment: @art_cs: but you don't need to specify the field. You simply write `invoice = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, to_field='invoice_id', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`. Django will automatically create an extra model field in **`ModelB`**, named `invoice_id`. So you could basically say that the `ForeignKey` will construct *two* model fields.

Comment: but it return product names , not invoice_id data

Comment: @art_cs: no it does not return product names. It returns a `ModelA` *object*. If you call `str(..)` on that, it will indeed return the name. If you thus use in in the shell, template, etc. it will call `str(..)` automatically on it. But you can easily write `mymodelb.invoice.admin`, or `mymodelb.invoice.invoice_id` for example, so it does not return a string. You can, as said before, prevent making a query to fetch the object, and just use `mymodelb.invoice_id` to obtain the value stored in the `ForeignKey` field, which is the field of the target model specified in the `to_field`.

Comment: i tried this in my template (form.invoice.invoice_id) i  make a model form from ModelB , and return nothing

Comment: @art_cs: in that case, you need to alter the form field with a `ModelChoiceField` with an override on `label_from_instance`.

Comment: in my forms.py > invoice = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ModelA.objects.all()) but how to define label_from_instance ? i much appreciate your helps

Comment: @art_cs: as in the edited answer. You subclass the `ModelChoiceField`, for example in a class `InvoiceChoiceField`, where you implement `label_from_instance`, and then you use this in the form.

Comment: sorry can you help me with this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63053941/check-then-update-method-in-mymodel-m2m-field-through-django